Unexplained s3 slowdowns when ingesting data to hudi tables using spark/python Glue jobs
I'm using AWS Glue Spark/python jobs to ingest data into hudi tables in a s3 bucket. I'm hitting major s3 slowdown issues, in a way that goes beyond reasonable, but unable to pin down the root cause.
My destination s3 bucket has a folder for every hudi table. When I ingest data to the tables sequentially (one table at a time - a very long run), all works well. However, when I run multiple jobs in parallel, each processing a single table, many of the jobs are failing with s3 slowdown errors.
This is not the expected behaviour, as the s3 rate limits are per prefix. Seeing as each hudi table has it's own folder, I assumed that each of those folders are a separate prefix, and should not be impacted by what's happening in other folders/prefixes. However, jobs do hit rate limits when running in parallel, unlike when running sequentially.
This is my hudi configuration:
 config = {
    'className' : 'org.apache.hudi',
        'hoodie.datasource.write.storage.type': 'COPY_ON_WRITE',
        'hoodie.datasource.hive_sync.use_jdbc': 'false',
        'hoodie.datasource.write.precombine.field': 'tx_commit_time',
        'path': targetPath, # s3 uri of the hudi table folder
        'hoodie.table.name': tableName,
        'hoodie.datasource.hive_sync.database': dbName,
        'hoodie.datasource.hive_sync.table': tableName,
        'hoodie.datasource.hive_sync.enable': 'true',
        'hoodie.datasource.write.hive_style_partitioning': 'true',
        'hoodie.datasource.write.keygenerator.class': 'org.apache.hudi.keygen.ComplexKeyGenerator',
        'hoodie.datasource.write.recordkey.field': hudiPrimaryKey,
        'hoodie.datasource.write.partitionpath.field': partitionKeyField,
        'hoodie.datasource.hive_sync.partition_extractor_class': 'org.apache.hudi.hive.MultiPartKeysValueExtractor',
        'hoodie.datasource.hive_sync.partition_fields': partitionKeyField,
        'hoodie.upsert.shuffle.parallelism': 20,
        'hoodie.insert.shuffle.parallelism': 20,
        'hoodie.datasource.write.operation': 'upsert',
        'hoodie.cleaner.policy': 'KEEP_LATEST_FILE_VERSIONS',
        'hoodie.cleaner.fileversions.retained': 1,
        'hoodie.datasource.write.reconcile.schema': 'true',
    'hoodie.index.type': 'GLOBAL_SIMPLE'
    }

My write operation is fairly straight forward:
outputDf.write.format('hudi').options(**config).mode('Append').save()

Can anyone please help clarify this behaviour and how to avoid it?

Despite the aws doc, I also had evidence that s3 quota are not related to prefix only, by observing collateral effects.
That being said there is couple of action to limit s3 call during hudi writes :

enable metadata table (MDT)
make use of the MDT during hive sync
enable timeline server

if not enough you can analyze your s3 actions by activating access logs in the bucket.

I finally found the answer with the help of the S3 support team -
So the key thing to understand (and that's not emphasised anough in the rate limit documentation in my opinion) is that the rate limits do not apply to prefixes (i.e. subfolders), but rather to partitioned prefixes - see here:

your application can achieve at least 3,500 PUT/COPY/POST/DELETE or 5,500 GET/HEAD requests per second per partitioned Amazon S3 prefix.

Now, what does partitioned prefix mean? This is something that end users do not have visibility over, and have no way of influencing themselves. Partitions are created and maintained behind the scenes by AWS, either automatically over time, or manually by the AWS support team as a response to a user-initiated support ticket requesting to manually add partitions.
To explain the effect - consider the following scenario:
A bucket has a folder structure, with files written and read across all subfolders at once. Without partitions, all actions across all subfolders in the bucket are counted towards a single rate limit, regardless of the prefix. However, once a partition is created for a prefix, only actions within that prefix will count towards the rate limit of that prefix, while anything else will count towards the general rate limit of the bucket. Partitions for nested prefixes create even further protection against hitting rate limits.
The more partitioned prefixes you have, the less likely you are to experience 503 slowdown errors. But again, out of the box, a bucket is completely unpartitioned regardless of the prefixes that are in it.
AWS claim that they have automatic processes to detect increased activity across areas of the s3 bucket (which is manifested in many 503 errors), to which the service will eventually respond by creating partitions for high traffic prefixes. However, they cannot commit to the time frame in which this will take before a partition will be created - they claim it could take days (during which you could expect 503 errors all over the place) but in my case it was 5 weeks before I gave up and raised a support request to manually create partitions for me - which they actioned immediately at no extra cost, and took ~48 hours to complete. Once completed - my 503 errors were completely gone.
One last thing to note is that the support people claim it's a best practice to contact them before hitting the bucket with high volume of activity, so that they can create partitions in advance. In our case, the prefix structure included a separate folder for each table in the data lake, and an ever growing number of subfolders underneath - one for each day of new incoming data. In order to solve for future data, the support team created partitions for future prefixes (i.e. for folders that didn't yet exist), so that when I ingest data into them in the future - those actions will not fail with 503 errors.
Not trivial, and not ideal, but that's how the service is designed and it solved my problem.

Not sure why their "internal architecture" doesn't create partitions automatically with prefixes? I can understand some hidden "storage costs". But couldn't they create partitions automatically by detecting "/key=value"? Just my opinion, I'm not AWS lol.

Also, not sure if you're aware, but the link you provided is broken. It might be this you're referring to: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/best-practices-to-optimize-data-access-performance-from-amazon-emr-and-aws-glue-to-amazon-s3/
However, they have removed the word partitioned so who knows what they're doing now


s3 rate limits are per prefix.

It's a bit more complex than that and the documentation is deliberately vague so they can change things.
Try turning on s3 server logging, then look in those logs for 503 throttle events. Remember to turn logging off after your experiments, unless you want to get billed for storage.
